# How can I decipher a ciphered text?

Tags: ruby, encoding, cryptography

I got the following ciphered string:

> MDExMDExMTEwMTExMDAwMDAxMTAwMTAxMDExMDExMTAwMDEwMDAwMDAxMTEwMDExMDExMDAxMDEwMTExMDAxMTAx MTAwMDAxMDExMDExMDEwMTEwMDEwMQ==

Now I would like to decipher this string into original one. How can I do this? and I don't know about which algorithm is used to cipher the original string, the ciphered string has length of 121 characters.

Comment: The `==` at the end suggests it's Base64 encoded. There is no encryption at play here.

Comment: Do you perchance have an Enigma machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artjom B. already noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122403/how-can-i-decipher-a-ciphered-text#comment67515763_40122403) that trailing equal signs may indicate a Base64 encoding (a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=trailing+equal+signs+encoding) reveals this, too). Fortunately, Ruby has a [`Base64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) library to decode it:

```
require 'base64'

string = 'MDExMDExMTEwMTExMDAwMDAxMTAwMTAxMDExMDExMTAwMDEwMDAwMDAxMTEwMDExMDExMDAxMDEwMTExMDAxMTAx MTAwMDAxMDExMDExMDEwMTEwMDEwMQ=='
decoded = Base64.decode64(string)
#=> "0110111101110000011001010110111000100000011100110110010101110011011000010110110101100101"
```

The new string consists of 0's and 1's, apparently another encoding, this time a binary one. It could be ASCII characters. Let's take a look at the first 8 "bits":

```
decoded[0, 8] #=> "01101111"
```

Converted to a byte, i.e. an integer via [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-to_i): (2 means binary)

```
decoded[0, 8].to_i(2) #=> 111
```

And finally to a character via [`chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
decoded[0, 8].to_i(2).chr #=> "o"
```

Nice, "o" is a valid ASCII character, what about the following characters?

```
decoded[8, 8].to_i(2).chr  #=> "p"
decoded[16, 8].to_i(2).chr #=> "e"
decoded[24, 8].to_i(2).chr #=> "n"
```

That's "open", an English word. I think we have something here. You can probably work out the rest yourself. And beware of the thieves ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot for detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult if you don't have any information about the algorithm, but the string looks like just base64 encoded, if you use a decoder you end up with

> 0110111101110000011001010110111000100000011100110110010101110011011000010110110101100101

don't know whether it makes sense or not

Comment: Ideally instead of just decoding you put in the code you used to do the decoding as that's the *educational* part.